# Using frequency dataset in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, import

I had a dataset with timestamp and x,y and z. I changed it to frequency domain and i saved it in frequencyFV.csv. This is a sample of new dataset:

[image]

Now i want to use it. By  the following codes i got error.

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/frequencyFV.csv')

X=data.iloc[:,1:]
```

this is error.
[image]

Comment: Can you post text rather than images, it helps others when trying to reproduce your errors, also if you txt really is formatted like that then you're parsing the entire row as a single element you need to pass a separator arg `data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/frequencyFV.csv', sep=' ')`

Comment: The error message is quite clear! You address an index which does not exist. So the next step has to be to control the data types and dimensions of data and its fields...

Comment: @EdChum thanks with your guide this problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default separator arg for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) is unsurprisingly a comma `,` but it looks like your txt file is space separated so you need to pass this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/frequencyFV.csv', sep=' ')
```